# Server chokes on php files from time to time

Tags: php, nginx, webserver

I am using Nginx on Windows for development testing, and every now and then A page won't load. Chrome just sits there and loads eventually a blank white page displays and this line gets put into nginx's error logs:

```
2013/02/10 12:21:34 [error] 936#4372: *406 WSARecv() failed (10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) while reading upstream, client: 24.179.144.72, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "24.179.144.72", referrer: "http://24.179.144.72/"
```

It seems to only happen with php pages, static pages seem to work fine. Afterwards the page works fine for a little bit then it happens again.

Has anyone had this issue and has found a fix for it?

Comment: assuming your only testing on localhost, if it doesn't happen on the live host i would ignore it.

Comment: What value do you have for `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN`

Comment: looks like `PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` isn't set.

Comment: I just recently had the same issue with Apache, I was able to fix this by converting from the 64bit to the 32bit, I assume that could fix my problem here as well.